# I am looking for suggestions on speeding up my Boyer-Moore-Horspool code

Tags: performance, fortran, boyer-moore

I wrote the below code in Fortran (my language of choice) thinking that it would be very fast. It turns out that it is quite fast but it is considerably slower than the FORTRAN intrinsic (Index) for finding sub-strings. To give an example, if I search a totally random string of 5,000,000 characters for the string "The moon's a balloon" which is located 1,000 chars in from the end of the string, I get the following timings (averaged out over 10 runs on a stock Intel HM370 (Cannon Lake-H)). I'm running Windows 10, using GCC Fortan with -O3 and -fno-checking optimization flags only);
My code (below) ~ 0.09 seconds
Intrinsic ~ 0.03 seconds
I am looking for any suggestions on refactoring the code to speed it up further.

```
  INTEGER FUNCTION BOYERMOORE(Text,Pat,Siztext,Sizpat) RESULT(SEARCH)
  IMPLICIT NONE
!
! Dummy arguments
!
  CHARACTER(*)  ::  Pat
  INTEGER  ::  Sizpat
  INTEGER  ::  Siztext
  CHARACTER(*)  ::  Text
  INTENT (IN) Pat, Sizpat, Siztext, Text
!
! Local variables
!
  LOGICAL  ::  found
  INTEGER  ::  i
  INTEGER  ::  j
  INTEGER  ::  k
  INTEGER  ::  maxchar
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(0:Siztext)  ::  skip

!Code starts here
  maxchar = Siztext
  found = .FALSE.
  SEARCH = 0
  IF(Sizpat==0)THEN                             ! Nothing to search for
     SEARCH = 1
     found = .TRUE.
  ENDIF
  skip(0:maxchar) = Sizpat
  DO k = 1, Sizpat - 1                          ! Setup the shift sizes
     skip(IACHAR(Pat(k:k))) = Sizpat - k
  ENDDO
  k = Sizpat
  DO WHILE ((.NOT.found) .AND. (k<=Siztext))    ! Scan
     i = k
     j = Sizpat
     DO WHILE (j>=1)                            ! Match the characters in substring
        IF(Text(i:i)/=Pat(j:j))THEN
           j = -1
        ELSE
           j = j - 1
           i = i - 1
        ENDIF
        IF(j==0)THEN                            ! Found 
           SEARCH = i + 1
           found = .TRUE.
        ENDIF
        k = k + skip(IACHAR(Text(k:k)))         ! Slide window right
     ENDDO
  ENDDO
  RETURN
  END FUNCTION BOYERMOORE
```

Comment: Note that the string you're searching for is short enough that you get about the same speedup by using a SIMD instruction to search for the first character, as you do by Boyer-Moore striding.  With a lot lower constant, because you don't need dynamic transitions.

Comment: The source code for gfortran's `INDEX` is available to read.  Have you considered comparing your code to gfortran's code?

Comment: @Ben Voigt - Thank you - this makes perfect sense. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with how to invoke SIMD from gcc Fortran. Do you have a suggestion/pointer? Normally, I simply try to structure the loops so the compiler vectorizes which can be a bit hit or miss.

Comment: @Steve - at your suggestion, I had a look. After a bit of digging, I turned up the source which appeared to be a Booyer-Moore algorithm in 'C'. It was logically the same as my code with the largest difference being that it used 'for' loops as opposed to 'while' loops. It was also structured so that there was no need for a boolean to indicate that the substring was found. All up, nothing obvious that would account for it being 3x faster unless the C compiler is optimizing the C code to vectorize the code better than mine.

Comment: @Pete: [Intel says "The SIMD intrinsic functions that are available to C and C++ developers do not have a corresponding Fortran interface"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/explicit-vector-programming-in-fortran)  That article might give some ideas but I'm not a FORTRAN programmer so I couldn't say for sure how to generate the combination of vectorized comparison and find-first-set-bit, both of which have intrinsics on my C++ compiler (the first is explicit SIMD, the other is a scalar operation).

Comment: @Pete, I haven't studied your code too closely, so I could be wrong.  In the C code from gfortran, one finds a `break` in the inner loop.  Do you want to exit the inner `do while` after you set `found = .true.`?

Comment: @Steve, the loops should be good. The found = .true. is set when J == 0, the loop that it is within is a "while J >= 1 loop so it should immediately exit after that. What I did look at was the physical size of the array "size" which holds the skip factor for the algorithm. I have it as a 4 byte integer, when I cut it down to a single byte integer, the algorithm speeds up a great deal, roughly equaling the intrinsic which suggests that cache may be an issue but I don't have the tools to confirm this.